# Address fields disappearing on civi

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

[image][image]So I was happily ticking along making webforms on Drupal for new contacts on civi.  The webforms consisted of adding contacts, registering for event amongst a couple of other components.  As I tried to make a new webform, contact details stopped being saved on civi.  I cannot for the life of me figure out what has changed.  Please can someone help. I am not a developer or a programmer, so in as basic instructions as possible please.

Comment: can you pls attach a screenshot to the Question showing part of the Form Compenents tab eg from /node/xxx/webform, and also for the CiviCRM tab, eg /node/xxx/civicrm

Comment: Hi there. I deleted my answer as I misunderstood the original question. If you select the Civicrm Tab on the webform, Do you still have the Enable Civicrm processing checkbox ticked?

Comment: If it helps we could do a quick screenshare to get you sorted - but otherwise provide the screenshot per Tony's request. ping me peter.davis59 or via pd@fuzion.co.nz

Comment: Hi, I’ve put the screenshot on my original post hopefully.

Comment: Have you been assigning any class to those address fields in component detail page? Also check if there are any errors in console tab of developer console. You can open it in chrome using shortcut "Ctrl+Shift+i".

Comment: What do you mean ‘assigning class’?